# Get string from a specif word to another word even if these words are more than once in a string

Tags: php

With a string like this one:

```
$sentence='StartDetails text 1 EndDetails StartDetails text 2 EndDetails  StartDetails text 3 EndDetails StartDetails text 4 EndDetails';
```

How can I get the text between `StartDetails` and `EndDetails` words even if they appear n numbers of times on string?

Comment: Is the structure always the same?

Comment: Yes, the only thing that would change would be just the text bextween `StartDetails` and `EndDetails`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your String has always the same structure: 
Using [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) within a loop is a possible option:

```
$sentence='StartDetails text 1 EndDetails StartDetails text 2 EndDetails  StartDetails text 3 EndDetails StartDetails text 4 EndDetails';

$a = explode("StartDetails", $sentence);

foreach($a as $k=>$v){
    if(!empty($v)){
        $b[] = explode( "EndDetails", $v)[0];
    }
}

print_r($b);

// output
Array
(
    [0] =>  text 1 
    [1] =>  text 2 
    [2] =>  text 3 
    [3] =>  text 4 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions should help, try this:

```
$sentence='StartDetails text 1 EndDetails StartDetails text 2 EndDetails  StartDetails text 3 EndDetails StartDetails text 4 EndDetails';

preg_match_all('/StartDetails(.*)EndDetails/U', $sentence, $outputArray);

print_r($outputArray);
```

In the `$outputArray`, the second element should be an array of all possible texts between StartDetails and EndDetails.

The key things to note here are the use of the `U` modifier, that makes the match greedy and the `preg_match_all` function instead of just `preg_match` which matches all occurrences

**EDIT**

Since we don't need to match StartDetails or EndDetails I have changed this

```
preg_match_all('/(StartDetails)(.*)(EndDetails)/U', $sentence, $outputArray);
```

to

```
preg_match_all('/StartDetails(.*)EndDetails/U', $sentence, $outputArray);
```

Comment: Prob don't need all of it `/StartDetails(.*)EndDetails/U`

Comment: This is true @AbraCadaver, I have made edits in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `(?<=StartDetails\s).*?(?=\s+EndDetails)`. It matches everything between `StartDetails` and `EndDetails`. The regex uses Lookahead and Lookbehind pattern to match more than one value.

Then use `preg_match_all` in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk`, `explode`

```
$senteanceToArray = array_filter(explode('StartDetails',$sentence));
array_walk($senteanceToArray, function(&$v, $k){
 return $v = trim(str_replace('EndDetails', '', $v));
});
echo '<pre>';
print_r($senteanceToArray);
```

You can use also `str_replace`

```
$sentence='StartDetails text 1 EndDetails StartDetails text 2 EndDetails  StartDetails text 3 EndDetails StartDetails text 4 EndDetails';
$patterns = ['StartDetails','EndDetails'];
$replacements = ['','#'];
$words = array_map('trim', array_filter(explode("#",str_replace($patterns, $replacements, $sentence))));
```

Result :-

```
Array
(
 [0] => text 1
 [1] => text 2
 [2] => text 3
 [3] => text 4
)
```